# timertask in blackberry, change schedule time without interrupting the execution?

Tags: multithreading, blackberry, timer, timertask

I'm using [TimerTask](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/java/util/TimerTask.html) to run some background process..

```
schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
```

i want to change the long period value without interrupting the task, from the next cycle of execution it should use the modified time..

is that possible without interrupting or should i cancel timerTask and restart again?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the interval of a running task, but I came up with this to tackle the problem. This is actually a Java-console program (as I have only Linux, and can't use the BlackBerry-environment at home), and I used private static classes just to make it work within a single file, but I think the idea should be quite clear:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Start a new task which runs every 1000ms
        TimerTest test = new TimerTest(1000L);
        TimerTaskStarter.startTask(test);

        //Wait for enter
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(!sc.nextLine().equals(""));

        //Change the interval (actually starts a new TimerTest after the current one runs next time)
        //since there's a new instance involved, the return value needs to be stored so it can be cancelled/controlled
        test = test.changeIntervalAtNextRun(500);

        //Wait for another enter        
        while(!sc.nextLine().equals(""));
        test.cancel();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static class TimerTaskStarter
    {
        public static void startTask(TimerTest task)
        {
            //Basic Timer-stuff
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(task, task.getInterval(), task.getInterval());
        }
    }

    private static class TimerTest extends TimerTask
    {
        /**
         * Current interval
         */
        private long interval;

        /**
         * Flag to indicate interval change at next run
         */
        private boolean changeInterval;

        /**
         * The new instance running with the new interval once started
         */
        private TimerTest nextInstance;


        public TimerTest(long interval)
        {
            this.interval = interval;
            changeInterval = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {   
            //The actual thing this task does goes here
            System.out.println("Running task");

            if(changeInterval == false)
            {
                //Not changing interval, just keep running
                System.out.println("Current interval is " + interval);
            }
            else
            {
                //Changing interval, cancel self and start new task
                System.out.println("Startingting new instance with interval " + interval);
                cancel();

                //Start a new task with new interval
                TimerTaskStarter.startTask(nextInstance);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Creates a new task with given interval. This task is cancelled and new task is automatically started
         * the next time this task runs
         * @param newInterval   Interval to run the new instance at
         * @return new TimerTest-instance
         */
        public TimerTest changeIntervalAtNextRun(long newInterval)
        {
            interval = newInterval;
            changeInterval = true;
            nextInstance = new TimerTest(interval);
            return nextInstance;
        }

        /**
         * Returns current interval
         * @return Interval as milliseconds
         */
        public long getInterval()
        {
            return interval;
        }
    }
}
```

So the class extending `TimerTask` (`TimerTest`) is capable of creating another instance of itself, which is started at requested interval the next time the task itself is run. `changeIntervalAtNextRun` returns the new instance which will be started automatically when the current task next runs. The current task also cancels itself at that point.

I made `TimerTaskStarter.startTask` static just to keep things simple, it could very well be some sort of manager-class holding all the currently running tasks, which could be passed into `TimerTest`'s `changeIntervalAtNextRun`, and the TimerTest-instance would give the new task directly to it. With multiple threads you'd probably need some sort of synchronization to occur also, but I haven't taken it into account in this example. Hope this helps (although the question is a couple of months old).